# Unable to set data fetched with beforeRouteEnter hook - vuesj2

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuejs2

I have an article component:

```
<template>
      <article class="content">
          <div class="content__inner">
              <h1 v-html="post.title" class="content__title"></h1>
                <div :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + post.image + ')' }" class="content__img"></div>
                <div class="content__meta">
                    <h5>by {{post.author}}</h5>
                    <h5>{{post.date}}</h5>    
                </div>
                <div v-html="post.content" class="content__text"></div>
          </div>
          <app-share></app-share>
          <!--<related :post="{category:post.categories,id:post.id}"></related>-->
  </article>

</template>

<script>
import Share from './Share.vue';
import RelatedPosts from './RelatedPosts.vue';
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
name:'article-gy',
components:{
    appShare:Share,
    related:RelatedPosts
},
  data(){
      return{
        post:{}
      }
  },
  created(){
      console.log('inside created',this.post)
     //this.$on('changeContent', post => {
          //this.post = post
          //document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
          //this.$router.push('/'+this.post.slug)
          //sessionStorage.setItem('currentPost',JSON.stringify(this.post))
      //})
  },
  destroyed(){
      //sessionStorage.removeItem('currentPost')
  },
  beforeRouteEnter(to,from,next){
      if(to.params.post){
        next(vm=>{
            vm.post.id = to.params.post.id
            vm.post.content = to.params.post.content.rendered
            vm.post.image = to.params.post.better_featured_image.source_url
            vm.post.author = to.params.post.post_author
            vm.post.date = to.params.post.date
            vm.post.title = to.params.post.title.rendered
            vm.post.categories = to.params.post.categories
            sessionStorage.setItem('currentPost',JSON.stringify(vm.post)) 
            console.log('inside next',vm.post.id) 
          })
      }
      else{
          axios.get('/posts?slug='+to.path)
          .then(response => response.data[0])
          .then(post =>{
              next(vm =>{
                  vm.post.content = post.content.rendered
                  vm.post.author = post.post_author
                  vm.post.image = post.better_featured_image.source_url
                  vm.post.date = post.date
                  vm.post.title = post.title.rendered
                  vm.post.categories = post.categories
                  vm.post.id = post.id
                  sessionStorage.setItem('currentPost',JSON.stringify(vm.post))
                  console.log('inside next',vm.post.id)
            })
        })
    }  
  }
}
</script>
```

in the `beforeRouteEnter` hook I'm trying to set some data with an if else condition, if the first condition apply, it means that the user come from another page that belong to the website, this page pass some data via the params object.

In the other case I do another request in order to fetch the correct post data related to the slug.

Now seem that the data are fetched but not displayed in the template. In the created hook if I console log the post variable I actually see the data, but I dont know why the post data are not displayed.

The strange thing is: if I do, in the created hook:

```
console.log(this.post)
```

I get the data, but if, for instance, I do:

```
console.log(this.post.id)
```

I get undefinded.

This not happens inside next, where I get the right data, even if I console log the `post.id`

How can this is possible?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I've tried another solution, avoiding the `beforeRouteUpdate` hook and working only with the `created` hook:

```
created(){
     //this.$on('changeContent', post => {
          //this.post = post
          //document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
          //this.$router.push('/'+this.post.slug)
          //sessionStorage.setItem('currentPost',JSON.stringify(this.post))
      //})
      if(this.$route.params.post){
          this.post.id = this.$route.params.post.id
            this.post.content = this.$route.params.post.content.rendered
            this.post.image = this.$route.params.post.better_featured_image.source_url
            this.post.author = this.$route.params.post.post_author
            this.post.date = this.$route.params.post.date
            this.post.title = this.$route.params.post.title.rendered
            this.post.categories = this.$route.params.post.categories
      }else{
          //console.log(this.$route.params.slug)//

          axios.get('/posts?slug='+this.$route.params.slug)
            .then(response => response.data[0])
                .then(post=>{
                    this.post.id = post.id
                    this.post.content = post.content.rendered
                    this.post.image = post.better_featured_image.source_url
                    this.post.author =  post.post_author
                    this.post.date = post.date
                    this.post.title = post.title.rendered
                    this.post.categories = post.categories
                    console.log('inside then',this.post)
                })
      }
  },
```

but doesnt' works anyway, if the route has the post object into `this.$route.params`, the content is loaded, else the content is fetched via axios but not displayed

Comment: solved using $forceUpdate(), works in both cases

Comment: Hi @lime could you post an example as answer, please? I'm stuck with a similar issue, I would see how to use this ```$forceUpdate()```. Many thanks.